# Why is the restored TensorFlow model, made with Keras, giving me 0 predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I made a classifier using MNIST digit data in Keras and I'm trying save and restore the model using only Tensorflow but I'm getting zeros for all ten of my classes.

Here is the classifier:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers.core import K
import tensorflow as tf

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28*28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')/255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28*28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')/255

from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

test_loss, test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print('\n\ntest_acc: ', test_acc)
print('\n' + network.input.op.name)
print('\n' + network.output.op.name)

sess = K.get_session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, './digit-model')
```

The results after running the script:

```
test_acc:  0.9799

dense_1_input

dense_2/Softmax
```

Here is the script where I pass my own image, resize to 28 * 28 and feed it to the saved model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

# First, pass the path of the image
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
image_path = './3.png'  # sys.argv[1]
filename = dir_path + '/' + image_path
image_size = 28
num_channels = 1
images = []

# Reading the image using OpenCV
image = cv2.imread(filename)

# Resizing the image to our desired size and pre-processing will be done exactly as done
# during training
image = cv2.resize(image, (image_size, image_size), 0, 0, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

if num_channels == 1:
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = np.reshape(image, (image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 1))

images.append(image)
images = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8)
images = images.astype('float32')
images = np.multiply(images, 1.0 / 255.0)

# The input to the network is of shape [None image_size image_size num_channels].
# Hence we reshape
x_batch = images.reshape(1, image_size * image_size)

# Let us restore the saved model
sess = tf.Session()

# Step-1: Recreate the network graph. At this step only graph is created.
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./digit-model.meta')

# Step-2: Now let's load the weights saved using the restore method
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

# Accessing the default graph which we have restored
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# for op in graph.get_operations():
#     print(str(op.name))

# Now, let's get hold of the op that we can be processed to get the output.
# In the original network y_pred is the tensor that is the prediction of the network
y_pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("dense_2/Softmax:0")

# Let's feed the images to the input placeholders
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("dense_1_input:0")
y_true = graph.get_tensor_by_name("dense_2/Softmax:0")
y_test_images = np.zeros((1, 10))

# Creating the feed_dict that is required to be fed to calculate y_pred
feed_dict_testing = {x: x_batch, y_true: y_test_images}
result = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict=feed_dict_testing)

for r in result:
    for i in r:
        print(i)
```

These are the results I get back:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the tensors I'm using for **y_true** and **y_pred**, I don't know which other tensor to use for them.  I would appriciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code, that you should feed only the `x_batch` for the graph.
So the solution is altering the original:

```
feed_dict_testing = {x: x_batch, y_true: y_test_images
```

to

```
  feed_dict_testing = {x: x_batch}
```

We don't need the line at all:
    `y_true = graph.get_tensor_by_name("dense_2/Softmax:0")`
Actually we don't need the `y_true` variable, we only need **true** labels for **training phase**.

You can change the rows as well:

```
images = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8)
images = images.astype('float32')
```

to

```
images = np.array(images, dtype=np.float32)
```

So, you win one row and save some plus computation.

As a result of our efforts we get some reasonable results for an arbitrary image.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./digit-model
3.4569392e-29
6.898592e-28
1.0
2.9526584e-16
0.0
7.1692116e-14
2.0023208e-12
1.9861456e-14
2.7171926e-23
1.3212834e-28
```

Comment: I get the following error:
`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 784, 1) for Tensor 'dense_1_input:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'`
That's why I had changed it form what the comments said.

Comment: @MarcoLugo I just realized, that you used Dense layer. See my updated answer.